# Как спрятать actionbar правильно?

Tags: android, actionbar

У меня есть активити и несколько фрагментов в ней, мне нужен actionbar, но есть только один фрагмент `MyTextFragment` где мне нужно его скрыть.

Мое активити это `AppCompatActivity` и для того, чтоб скрыть actionbar из активити я делаю это так

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        supportActionBar?.hide()
...
```

и это работает, но мне нужно сделать этот вызов из фрагмента, вот так к примеру

```
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.hide()

    }
```

вот что получается

[image]

actionbar становиться invisible вместо gone, то есть мы видим эту серую полосу вместо actionbar

что делаю не так?

**UPD**

Я хочу еще раз показать проблему здесь, вот сделал вот такой код для теста

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        
        Thread {
            Thread.sleep(8000)

            mainExecutor.execute {
                supportActionBar?.show()      <---- 2
            }
        }.start()

        Thread {
            Thread.sleep(12000)

            mainExecutor.execute {
                supportActionBar?.hide()     <---- 3
            }
        }.start()

        supportActionBar?.hide()          <---- 1
...
```

что происходит здесь, первым вызывается метод `hide` и тулбар действительно прячется так как ожидается, его просто не видно, потом через 8 секунд происходит следующий вызов `show()` и тулбар появляется так как ожидается, еще через несколько секунд происходит последний 3й вызов снова `hide()` и вот тут наблюдается баг который я описываю в вопросе - остается серая полоса.
То есть такое чувство, что если я пытаюсь скрыть тулбар после того как активити было создано, то это сделать нормально не получается, остается серая полоса. Судя по результатам теста - это нужно делать либо сразу в момент `OnCreate()` либо никак...

**UPD**

MainActivity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/awl_application_drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_activity_layout_bg_color"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <application.widget.toolbar.BondToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/errorViewContainer"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_layout"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            style="@style/AppTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_nav_tab_height"
            android:background="@color/deprecated_palette_FF000000"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:tabMinWidth="@dimen/bottom_nav_tab_min_width" />

        <CustomView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tab_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: а так ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();

Comment: @Style-7 так я вроде в вопросе описал этот подход и показал на скриншоте, что это не работает...

Comment: возможно "серый фон" это не supportActionBar, попробуйте фон для него поменять на  красный например

Comment: @Style-7 добавил mainactivity layout

Comment: А нельзя сделать кастомный ActionBar и уже его рулить?

Comment: Скорее всего как вы дополнили, можно менять видимость только в onCreate. Единственное что можно попробовать менять высоту ActionBar но не уверен.